# how to get values from xml response

Tags: c#, xml

how to get address and netmask values from the following xml response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
    - <controls>
      <ManualCalib>0</ManualCalib> 
      <MaintMode>0</MaintMode> 
      <AntEnable>0</AntEnable> 
      <ChgBeamEnable>1</ChgBeamEnable> 
      <ModemResponse>options show ETH0_1 [ETH0_1] address = 10.171.74.1 netmask = 255.255.255.0 rip_enabled = 0 [RMT:416] admin@telnet:::ffff:127.0.0.1;4709 ></ModemResponse> 
      </controls>
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution would be to find out the exact structure of the ModemResponse string. You could write a regular expression to capture the values you need, or have more robust parsing logic. If you don't know the exact structure, you could write some hacky code like this to get it done in most cases:

```
        var xd = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        var modemResponse = xd.Element("controls").Element("ModemResponse").Value;
        string address = string.Empty, netmask = string.Empty;
        var tokens = modemResponse.Split(new[] { ' ', '=' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Length; i++)
        {
            var token = tokens[i];
            switch (token)
            {
                case "address":
                    if (i + 1 < token.Length)
                        address = tokens[i + 1];
                    break;
                case "netmask":
                    if (i+1 < tokens.Length)
                        netmask = tokens[i+1];
                    break;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("address: {0}, netmask: {1}", address, netmask);
```